# How to convert an array of (00s...11s), the binary representation of each character, to a string of char

Tags: java, loops, char, decimal, int

How to convert an array of (00s...11s), the binary representation of each character, to a string of char? In my code I take int array of length 64, then divide the array multiple times, each time I take 8 indexes equivalent to 8 bits, then start from index 7 from the array of length 8, then multiply the value of the index by (2^index number which should be 7 for the first time, then 6. etc.)

But I receive an exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
    at testing.cipherText(testing.java:30)
    at testing.main(testing.java:8)
```

If my algorithm is not correct, please tell me

```
import java.util.*; 

public class testing { 

 public static void main(String [] args)
 {
     int [] array ={0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1};
     String c = cipherText (array);
     //System.out.print(i);
 }

 public static String cipherText (int [] array)
 {
     int decimal = 0;
     int [] intA = new int [8];
     int from = array.length;
     char x = 0;
     int dre;
     String s = null;
     for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i = i + 8)
     {
          from=from-8;
          intA=copyPartOfArray(array,from,8);
          for (int j=0;j<intA.length;j++)
          {
              dre = (int) Math.pow (2.0, (double)7-i);
              dre = dre * intA[i];
              decimal = decimal+dre;
              x =(char)decimal;
           }
           s=x+s;
        }         
        return s;
    }
    public static int [] copyPartOfArray (int [] a, int from, int to) // return a subArray 
    {
        int [] result=new int [to];
        System.arraycopy(a,from, result, 0, to); 
        return result;
    } 
}
```

Comment: write your question with a bit of punctuation, please.. for me it's difficult to understand your flux of sentences

Comment: I suggest you try this in a debugger. I also suggest you look at ways to simplify your code.  You also appear to be building your string is reverse order.

Comment: If you want to multiple a number by a power of 2 you can use the shift operator <<.

Comment: multiplication is not my interest, all what i want is to convert this array of int to a string of character .i used this multiplication to define the equivalent  number in radix 10 ,then do some casting to have chars then concatenate them to get the final string

Answer (score 3):

Without creating a new array:

```
public static String cipherText(int[] array) {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length / 8; i++) {
        byte dec = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            int pow = 1 << 7 - j; // == Math.pow(2, 7 - j)
            dec += array[i * 8 + j] * pow;
        }
        s.append((char) dec);
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, your problem is you are saying

```
dre = (int) Math.pow(2.0, (double) 7 - i);
dre=dre*intA[i];
```

I think you wanted

```
dre = (int) Math.pow(2.0, (double) 7 - j);
dre=dre*intA[j];
```

Also you should initalise your string

```
    String s = "";
```

instead of

```
    String s = null;
```

What output are you expecting, from the array.
Remember also, chars in java are 16bit unicode.
Still, I don't think your algorithm works quite yet...
Will keep looking

Answer (score 0):

you might want to compare with ...

```
public static String cipherText(int[] array) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[array.length / 8];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i += 8)
        bytes[i / 8] = (byte) ((array[i] << 7) + (array[i + 1] << 6) + (array[i + 2] << 5) + (array[i + 3] << 4) 
                + (array[i + 4] << 3) + (array[i + 5] << 2) + (array[i + 6] << 1) + array[i]);
    return new String(bytes, 0);
}
```

Comment: when i run yours i got testing.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: It deprecated in favour of new String(byte[], Charset) which supports character encoding.  I assumed you haven't used a character encoding, so it is appropriate for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Without using `pow` or `<<`, just standard `parseByte`:

```
int [] array={0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,
              0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,
              0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,
              0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,
              0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,
              0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,
              0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,
              0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1};
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
assert array.length % 8 == 0;
for(int current:array) {
  buffer.append(current);
}   
int steps = array.length/8;
byte [] letters = new byte[steps];
for(int i=0; i<steps; i++) {
   letters[i] = Byte.parseByte(buffer.substring(i*8, i*8+8), 2); 
}   
String result = new String(letters);
System.err.println(result);
```

}